# thoughts on innerjoin mysql

Tags: mysql

We have tables with more then 3m records. When using `innerjoin` it is much slower then `select * from db1,db2 where db1.field=db2.field`

Any thoughts?

Comment: what version of MySQL, what does the "join" version look like?

Comment: You're asking us to compare the performance of two queries on a large table. Some information that might help: 1. The first query. 2. The second query. 3. The schema of the table. Just a thought.

Comment: (And you thought *you* were grumpy.) ;-)

Comment: ... is db1.field indexed? is db2.field indexed? What types are they? Have you established a Foreign Key relationship between the fields? (Not remembering if the latter applies to MySQL...)

Comment: I was talking in general. We dont use inner join anymore. But i see it here in a lot of sample code

Comment: sample
table1 950k records
table2 1.4m records
both have field uniek wich joins them together

if we do select with join on the uniek field is much slower
then the sample i wrote before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT * from t1, t2 where t1.id = t2.id

is equivalent to

SELECT * from t1 INNER JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.id.

However, if there are other criteria for the SQL query, then the behaviour may differ. For instance.

SELECT * from t1, t2 where t1.id = t2.id and t1.col1 is not null;

can be written in two different ways with the INNER JOIN:

SELECT * from t1 INNER JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.col1 is not null

or

SELECT * from t1 INNER JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.col1 is not null

This may or may not end up being the same query (according to the optimiser), and the complexity of the other parts of the query. The EXPLAIN PLAN will tell you if you are executing the same query.

Why are the above queries different? Because the restriction on not null is done at different stages of the query, which may have an impact on the performance, or even on the number of rows returned.

Answer (score 5):

INNER JOIN should not be any different from a SELECT FROM t1,t2 WHERE t1.c=t2.c, it is just a different syntax for doing the same thing and is treated the same by the optimiser.

Any difference in performance is in some other aspect of the query. Please POST:

1. The schema of both tables including their indexes (SHOW CREATE TABLE gives you this)
2. Both the queries you're comparing
3. Some detail about your performance testing methodology (it may be flawed)
4. The EXPLAIN output of both queries.

If you want a reasonable answer.

Comment: i will get back with a sample later. The info i can give right now is that both tables have index on the fields uniek.

Comment: No. 4 is the prime clue. If the explain plan for two queries is different, then you don't have the same query. If it is the same plan, then it's the same query, unless there are variables involved.

Answer (score 3):

In *general*, the `...where db1.field=db2.field...` syntax **is** an inner join. It's just the implicit notation instead of the explicit. If you're joining on the same columns and *returning* the same columns, performance should be identical. More: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join

Answer (score 0):

I generally use explicit `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` syntax according to needs. When the optimizer does a bad job, a `STRAIGHT_JOIN` can often sort it out, with suitable rearrangement of the query.

With any join involving large tables, it's worth using `EXPLAIN`.